# NEAR SmartContract promises usage

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol

It's not an obvious thing when I should use Promises when developing SmartConract in NEAR Protocol. And when it's redundant.

For example, I have some logic that finalize some public methods:

```
    #[private]
    fn record_data(&mut self, key: &Vec<u8>) -> Balance {
        let initial_storage = env::storage_usage();
        assert!(
            !self.used_events.contains(&key),
            "Proof event cannot be reused. Proof already exist."
        );
        self.used_events.insert(&key);
        let current_storage = env::storage_usage();
        let attached_deposit = env::attached_deposit();
        let required_deposit =
            Balance::from(current_storage - initial_storage) * STORAGE_PRICE_PER_BYTE;
        attached_deposit - required_deposit
    }
```

And in the same contract I have a function:

```
    #[payable]
    fn deposit(&mut self, amount: Balance) {
        // ...some logic
        self.record_data(&data)
    }
```

So with Promises, I can call `record_data` in `async` way.
But it's not clear when I must use that way (Promise call). And when I can call in a very simple manner:

```
self.record_data(&data)
```

It's an obvious fact, that cross-contract call always via Promises.
But it the same contract call specific inner Contract functions -it's not clear when we should use Promises.

So I need good clarification when I must use Promises and when it will redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the call  to `record_data` async, but it comes at a cost.  You are paying a base fee to make another transaction + the gas cost to run the code + the gas to interact with the host calls (e.g. `env::*`).  So the reason to make internal calls asynchronous is to take advantage of the concurrency: see the [rust-sdk's merge sort](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/661a14ead9c98c6a892937531d84418fe2af9baf/examples/cross-contract-high-level/src/lib.rs#L59)

```rust
    pub fn merge_sort(&self, arr: Vec<u8>) -> PromiseOrValue<Vec<u8>> {
        if arr.len() <= 1 {
            return PromiseOrValue::Value(arr);
        }
        let pivot = arr.len() / 2;
        let arr0 = arr[..pivot].to_vec();
        let arr1 = arr[pivot..].to_vec();
        let prepaid_gas = env::prepaid_gas();
        let account_id = env::current_account_id();

        ext::merge_sort(arr0, &account_id, 0, prepaid_gas / 4)
            .and(ext::merge_sort(arr1, &account_id, 0, prepaid_gas / 4))
            .then(ext::merge(&account_id, 0, prepaid_gas / 4))
            .into()
    }
```

Comment: 1. So advantages of Promises only for concurrency approach?
2. Explained a bit more how it will be executed. Because it'll create a Receipt, so it can execute in any other host (node) in Blockchain (it means not the same execution host)?
3. What concrete formula mean:  prepaid_gas / 4, how I decide to divide to number 4?

Comment: 1. It's also for cross contract interaction; You could have a `then` promise that uses a callback on an internal method, which then lets you check the success of the call.

Comment: 2. In this example the result of the initial contract call will be the value returned by the final call in the chain.  The receipts track this and it is handled by the runtime.

3. You need to provide enough gas to cover the costs.  The `4` in this formula comes from the four transactions, current one and the three promises.  However, the initial transaction probably is being over paid. There is also `env::used_gas`